# How to update the props value in child component dynamically from parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have a parent component eg. parent.vue through which I'm passing a props property to a child component.

Basically, I am using vue-chartjs and have my chart data in child component and passing its data, label and other properties from parent component as props.

In the parent component, I have 3 buttons week, month, year on clicking of buttons I am changing the chart data and sending that changed data in child component as props. Data is getting changed in parent component but not in the child component (When I console). So how do I update the value of data in child component as well on clicking?
If you need some code, let me know.

**Parent Component**

```
   <button @click="changeBtn('euro')"></button>
   <button @click="changeBtn('pound')"></button>
   <tr v-for="(row,index) in selectedCurrency">
        <td>{{ index }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.desktop_name }}</td>                         
        <td>
          <div>
            <line-chart-shadow-v3
                :dataSet="row.data"
                :lineTension="0.5"
                :dataLabels="row.label"
                :width="50"
                :height="80"
            >
            </line-chart-shadow-v3>
          </div>
         </td>  
         <td>{{ row.data }}</td>    
   </tr>

//script part below

data () {
        return {
            selectedBtn: 'dollar',
            selectedCurrency: [],
            currencyList,
            }
         },
methods:(){
    mounted(){
        this.getSelectedCurrency();
    },
    methods: {
        getSelectedCurrency(){
            this.selectedCurrency = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < currencyList.length; i++){
                if(currencyList[i].tag == this.selectedBtn){
                    this.selectedCurrency.push(currencyList[i]);
                    console.log(this.selectedCurrency)
                }
          }
        },
      changeBtn(value){
            this.selectedBtn = value;
            this.getSelectedCurrency();
      }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
...
props: {
        dataSet: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [10, 30, 39, 65, 85, 10, 10]
        },
        lineTension: {
            type: Number,
            default: () => 0.4
        },
        dataLabels: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
      },
    },



...
mounted() {
        let self=this;

        this.renderChart({
            labels: this.dataLabels,
            datasets: [{
               labels: this.label1,
                data: this.dataSet,
                lineTension: this.lineTension,
                borderColor: gradientColor,
                pointBorderWidth: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 0,
                borderWidth: this.borderWidth,
                fill: false
            }]
        }, this.options)
        console.log(this.dataSet)
    }
```

Comment: We need some code

Comment: @fabruex ok I will give you the code right away. Did you get the idea what I am trying to asking?

Comment: Yes. Please post relevant code of parent and child components (also with the console.log)

Comment: @fabruex Please check, I updated the code.

Comment: Where do you call the renderChart function? On mounted?

Comment: @fabruex yes on mounted

Comment: Have you tried using the watch updating hook to watch after a props change in the child component?

Comment: @MaikenMadsen I console the dataset value which is coming through the props in child component it does not updated. so how come the watch property will work? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you uploade the code where you parse the props from the parent and the code where you receive it in the child?

Comment: @MaikenMadsen I have already uploaded it, You can check in my question. In the parent component, I'm passing :dataset as prop to LineChartShadowV3 component.  In child component receiving it in the prop object.